# useState weird update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, use-state

I have this function that get some data and put in a array, and, in the end, change de value of the **test** useState to the content of that array

```
const [teste, setTeste] = useState('DefaultValue');
const fetchTeses = () => {
      const textTeses = [];
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/teses')
      .then(res => {
          if(!res.ok){
              throw Error('Could not fetch the data for that resource')
          }
          return res.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        items.forEach((element, index) => {
          tesesEscolhidas.forEach((teseEscolhida) => {
            if(element.indexOf(teseEscolhida)!=-1){
              textTeses.push(data[index]['Content']);
            }
          })
        })
      }).then((data) => {
        setTeste(textTeses)
      })
    }
```

This function is called by clicking on a button:

```
<Button color="secondary" size="large" variant="contained" onClick={fetchTeses}>Resetar</Button>
```

But I call the **test** useState in another function, which is called by clicking in another button:

```
<Button color="primary" size="large" variant="contained" onClick={generateFromUrl}>Criar arquivo docx</Button>
```

The second function:

```
    const generateFromUrl = async() => {
      const blob = await fetch(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dolanmiu/docx/master/demo/images/cat.jpg"
      ).then(r => r.blob());
  
      const doc = new Document({
        sections: [
          {
            children: [
              new Paragraph(teste[0])
            ]
          }
        ]
      });
  
      Packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
        console.log(blob);
        saveAs(blob, nameFile+".docx");
        console.log("Document created successfully");
      });
    }
```

But the weird part is that when I call the **test**  useState in the second function he pass the **DefaultValue**, even though I have already executed the first function and already assigned the new value to the **test** useState. (I notice that if I execute the first function more than once, the new value is finally assigned)

However, when I create an element with **test** useState value and do the exaclty same thing, the value passed in the second function is the new value assigned in the first function, which is what i want to happen.

Example:

```
<TextField id="nameTest" label="Teste" variant="outlined" color="primary" fullWidth helperText="Teste" value={teste ? teste : ''} />
```

Why is this happening and how to avoid this?

I know this has to do with the render thing, but I really can't figured out how to made this works.

Comment: What if you put this attribute `disabled={teste === 'DefaultValue'}` in your docx generation button ? That way it can only be pressed when the image is fetched